# deleting a child from firebase when flagging a post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have been trying to delete a post from firebase when the post gets more then 2 flags. I have tried a lot of ways and I cannot figure it out. I have some images attached help would be appreciated!
`

```
 // 4
        if poster.uid != User.current.uid {
            let flagAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report as Inappropriate", style: .default) { _ in
                PostService.flag(post)

            /// addedflag

            let flaggedPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("flaggedPosts").child(postKey!)


            // 3
            var flaggedDict = ["text": post.textData,
                               "poster_uid": post.poster.uid,
                               "reporter_uid": User.current.uid]

            // 4
            flaggedPostRef.updateChildValues(flaggedDict)

            // 5
            let flagCountRef = flaggedPostRef.child("flag_count")
            flagCountRef.runTransactionBlock({ (mutableData) -> TransactionResult in


                let currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0
                mutableData.value = currentCount

            if mutableData.value as! Int >= 1 {



                let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.poster.uid!.uid

                // Remove the post from the DB
                ref.child("posts").child(postKey).removeValue { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error \(error)")
                    }
                }
                postKey?.removeVolue()
                let timelinePostDict = ["poster_uid" : poster.uid]
                var updatedData: [String : Any] = ["timeline/\(poster.uid)/\(postKey)" : timelinePostDict]

                let postToBeDeleted = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
                updatedData["timeline/\(poster.uid)/\(postKey)"] = timelinePostDict
                updatedData["posts/\(poster.uid)/\(postKey)"] = postKey


                print("Delete case: mutableData.value = \(mutableData.value)")

            } else {
                print("Case not met. Either not equal to 2 or not able to cast as Integer type. The value of the casted in is \(mutableData.value as? Int)")
            }




                mutableData.value = currentCount + 1


                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: mutableData)
            })
```

`[the code for flaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UoH.png)   [Friebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh6fi.png)

Comment: the extended code for flaging is here I was not able to post it.

Comment: that's an interesting problem.... i've been using firebase quite a bit lately and this is a good question! Let's see if i can throw an idea at you here after i've had a moment to think about it.

Comment: Where is your flaggedPosts in firebase, show that image also?how are saving the flags in firebase?

Comment: @user1000 I connote post any more images for some reason but my flagged post is right on top followers which are on top of post likes. and it has the flagged posts uid as child

Comment: @user1000 also something I hadn't mentioned I figured out a way to delete the post in Firebase but only under the flagged posts branch so the actual post doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @archae0pteryx the method that I wanted to take was //1. Figure out how you want to get the post key when you flag
//2. Based on that, update your postToBeDeleted reference
//3. Then call the function .removeValues() on both the (a) flagged post references and (b) the actual post. But it didn't really worked out and I was not able to do the steps

Comment: yeah. it's actually a tricky little problem there... a good head scratcher.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture an error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the advice. I didn't know we could do that and I added it

Comment: Whats your Database JSON architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.runTransactionBlock({..` gets triggered multiple times before the value is appended/updated at a particular node. What you need is an observer :-

```
Database.database().reference().child("flaggedPosts").observe(.childChanged, with: {(Snapshot) in

        // Every time a child dictionary in the flaggedPosts node
        // would change you will receive that dictionary in this block
        // be it any change in any of the values in that postKey
        // Check the flagCount value and perform the action requisite... 

        print(Snapshot.value ?? "No value retrieved")



        if let snapDict = Snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{

            let count = snapDict["count"] as! Int
            let postID = snapDict["postKey"] as! String
            let posterUID = snapDict["poster_uid"] as! String

            if count > 1{

                print(postID)

                // You will only be pushed into this block only if your count value
                // is greater than 1 i.e 2

                // Delete postID in your database

                Database.database().reference().child("posts/\(posterUID)/\(postID)").removeValue(completionBlock: {(Err, ref) in

                    // Handle the error you recieve while deleting 
                    // the flagged post


                })
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: {(Error) in

        // Handle the error recieved while making 
        // a call to firebase

    })
```

Given that this method uses an `.observe(.childChanged..`, this is an asynchronous active call whose observer is not removed from the network link. to your database which will get triggered every time your child is changed/updated...

Comment: THank you, I just fixed using similar ways. Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

```
let flaggedPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("flaggedPosts").child(postKey!)
```

I fixed it - I just found a way to find the poster uid and post key and just remove the value.